# Is this possible to race condition or something collision when execute a function?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm a newbie to know programming. First language I choose is Python. I'm also a newbie with multi-threading, multi-processing world, so I have a dummy question (I guess): if I create a function or object callable, and multi threads run this function (concurrent). Race condition or collision or something like that can happen? My function just handle value is passed to as parameter.

For instance,

```
def my_func(data):
    // handle data
```

or

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        // setup some config
    def __call__(self, data):
        // handle data

# global setup
obj = MyClass()

# in thread 1
data1 = Data(...)
obj(data1)

# in thread 2
data2 = Data(...)
obj(data2)
```

So the problem is if 2 `"obj(data)"` occur at the same time, `obj` will handle which `"data"` ?

### **Update:**

2 `data` is different totally.

Comment: As long as they aren't modifying a common `data` object no collision will occur.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)

Comment: _"Race condition or collision or something like that can happen?"_ Yep. _"obj will handle which data?"_ Both of them. It's hard to give a more comprehensive answer than that, since you've only supplied this sample code.

Comment: @PauloBu: 2 `data` is different totally.

Comment: From this information it is very hard to say, you have one function that operates on different pieces of data according to what is inferred, however if there are any globals or members modified inside the MyClass then there could be side effects.